# ModelAndView object not returned to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to return a simple String "HelloSpring" from controller to jsp. Controller is

```
package it.polito.ai.e4;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloSpringController
{
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView helloSpring(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String message = "HelloSpring";
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
}
}
```

jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%=(String)request.getAttribute("message")%>
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute this on Tomcat 7 I get "null" string on page's body. My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>ai4</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ai4</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ai4</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: In order to use `(String)request.getAttribute("message")` you have to `request.setAttribute("message")` first.

Comment: then I think you only have to return the view you want the controller to go to. In this case, instead of `return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);` just use `return "hello"`;

Comment: Thanks, I thought that in Spring attributes had to be passed via ModelAndView constructor.

Comment: Maybe, which is why I am only posting comments because I don't know for sure. I never used Spring before.

Comment: try `${message}` instead of `<%=(String)request.getAttribute("message")%>`, though I think it should work either way. This is the preferred approach to accessing model objects.

Comment: Ah ok. Me too, I used struts before but reading some Spring tutorial it seemed to be different..

Comment: @steve.hanson tried before but with no different results..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` instead of `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView`. :)

Also, as Sumit Desai mentioned, since Spring 3, most people write their controller methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String helloSpring(Model m)
{
    m.addAttribute("message", "HelloSpring");
    return "hello";
}
```

It's just style, and what you've done works too. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably misconfigured your view resolver.  In particular, I would double-check the "viewClass" attribute of your view resolver.  Post your spring config so we can check.

Answer (score 0):

${message} should work for you.
Also, it looks that you are using Spring 3.x. So, better approach would be using a ModelMap object , which allows you to pass multiple model objects to the JSP(Return type of your method helloSpring should be String in this case, which will correspond to the name of the JSP page), though yours is also not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issues and my program was already taking care of solutions in the answer mentioned here. I came across this post while finding the solution http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el/ . So as per the link I added a statement at the top of my jsp file "<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> " and it started working out fine. Hope it helps.