# Spring returning null ModelAndView to DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a minimal reproduction of a spring mvc project for use in diagnosing errors in more complex projects.  But when I try to click on the url that triggers a controller method, the eclipse console gives an error indicating that the ModelAndView is null.  While [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214143/null-modelandview-returned-to-dispatcherservlet) asks about a similar error, you can see that the question was not answered because four separate people gave +1 to the comment that the answer needs to be elaborated upon.  I also looked at [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621717/modelandview-object-not-returned-to-jsp), but following it's advice of using `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` instead of Map did not resolve the problem.  Also, I would like to use Map if possible, because Map works in my more complex apps.  **How can I resolve this error?**

Here is the controller method being called when the error is thrown:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/TriggerTheError", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {        
    return "ReproduceError";
}
```

The console prints out the following log when the above-controller method is called:

```
13:59:10.874 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'MinimalDbaseExample' processing GET request for [/MinimalDbaseExample/TriggerTheError]
13:59:10.874 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /TriggerTheError
13:59:10.874 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/TriggerTheError]
13:59:10.875 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/TriggerTheError] are [/**]
13:59:10.875 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/TriggerTheError] are {}
13:59:10.875 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/TriggerTheError] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@186a461c] and 1 interceptor
13:59:10.875 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/MinimalDbaseExample/TriggerTheError] is: -1
13:59:10.875 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'MinimalDbaseExample': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
13:59:10.875 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

---

**Answer**

---

The solution was to simply remove the BindingResult because it was not needed in this situation.  By removing the BindingResult from the arguments to the controller method, the error was removed.  Later on, if BindingResult is required, the solution then would simply be to add the other required elements for BindingResult which are not required for this test case.

**I will mark the other user's answer as accepted.  However, the preceding paragraph is the solution that resolved the problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to return the string `ReproduceError`, then mark the return value with `@ResponseBody`.

On the other hand, if you've got a View called `ReproduceError` then perhaps your view resolver isn't configured properly?

**EDIT**: ok, looks like a rendering of the `ReproduceError` view is intended, but from the logfile it seems that the controller method isn't being hit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the type who runs random code I found on the internet!
However, I can tell you that your edited post has already told me something - I don't think your method is being hit!
I'm willing to look at the rest of your log file though, can you post that somewhere?

Comment: I added the answer to the end of my OP.  I am also marking yours as the answer and +1 to thank you for looking into this.  Separately, a zipped eclipse project is just a collection of folders and classes with some configs.  In this case, the contents were so minimalistic that it would only have taken a few minutes to simply cut and paste files into a new project and to read each file rather than just blindly importing.  But the problem is solved now anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't mark an answer as accepted just to thank somebody. Somebody in the future will look at this answer for guidance.